# openstack: Failed to launch instance from the glance

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, openstack-horizon, openstack-glance

We have setup OpenStack using conjure-up on a (Ubuntu LTS server 16.04.3) single machine. All are services are up and running, and successfully I am able to upload images to the glance.

We wanted to save these glance images created by "glance image-create" in remote machine which have nfs server. So we have configured glance-api.conf file as below.

My glance-api.conf looks like this:

```
[glance_store]
filesystem_store_datadir = /var/lib/glance/images
default_store = file
```

And in glance controller node, I have mounted

`remote machine Ip/home/glance/images/` in this directory path 
`/var/lib/glance/images`

and have mentioned the same mounted directory path inside the glance-api.conf file.

I have created the two sample private network with some ip (192.168.1.0 and 10.221.50.0) but have not created a public network as at this moment I don't want to access this VM instance from outside.

When I am trying to launch the instance from dashboard UI as well as through CLI, I am getting below error.

```
Error: Failed to perform requested operation on instance "Ubuntu_Hawkbit", the instance has an error status: Please try again later [Error: No valid host was found. There are not enough hosts available.].
```

Note: I have tried by associating Instance with different private network ,thinking that it may be network IP address issue but facing the same error.

When I check /var/log/nova/nova-compute.log logs, I see below error.

```
ERROR nova.image.glance [req-1459f1b2-491c-46a2-b803-6ff621a79d30 6ebc7996240c4ce688234f544c9d0116 07427c9d49704357a049b24193ee0a28 - -
   -] Error contacting glance server 'http://10.206.193.159:9292' for 'data', done trying.  
ERROR nova.image.glance CommunicationError:
   Error finding address for
   http://10.206.193.159:9292/v1/images/6c30e2ab-1078-45ad-bed2-3e3a75f6af8c:
   ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))   
ERROR
   nova_lxd.nova.virt.lxd.image
   [req-1459f1b2-491c-46a2-b803-6ff621a79d30
   6ebc7996240c4ce688234f544c9d0116 07427c9d49704357a049b24193ee0a28 - -
   -] [instance: eedc008d-ef34-498d-8774-b3813ce032f4] Failed to upload 6c30e2ab-1078-45ad-bed2-3e3a75f6af8c to LXD: Connection to glance 
ERROR nova_lxd.nova.virt.lxd.operations
   [req-1459f1b2-491c-46a2-b803-6ff621a79d30
   6ebc7996240c4ce688234f544c9d0116 07427c9d49704357a049b24193ee0a28 - -
   -] [instance: eedc008d-ef34-498d-8774-b3813ce032f4] Faild to start container instance-00000020: Connection to glance host
   http://10.206.193.159:9292 failed: Error finding address for
   http://10.206.193.159:9292/v1/images/6c30e2ab-1078-45ad-bed2-3e3a75f6af8c:
   ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))  
ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-1459f1b2-491c-46a2-b803-6ff621a79d30
   6ebc7996240c4ce688234f544c9d0116 07427c9d49704357a049b24193ee0a28 - -
   -] [instance: eedc008d-ef34-498d-8774-b3813ce032f4] Instance failed to spawn
```

Comment: I would suggest you copy the error message and ask the question in the nova IRC channel (#openstack-nova at the freenode). `No valid host was found` seems like a `nova` issue to me rather than `glance.`

Comment: Is 10.206.193.159 the right IP address for the glance service? Also, you can check if glance is listening on that IP or not by doing: "netstat -tulpn | grep 9292" and ensuring that it is listening on *:9292 instead of just local host. Also, copy paste the glance related lines from nova.conf.

Comment: @PraveenYalagandula, Yes  10.206.193.159 is the IP of glance service node.And glance is listening on 9292. Please find below details inside glance node.